# jquery : focus out for windows (browser page)

Tags: jquery

I came up with a problem that my website users are cheating on online games . For the cheating part they need to do some part of the flash games and then switch the window and use their desktop applications to cheat and change the records

Now , I think if I find a way to stop users from switching windows while they are playing I can stop these cheats.

I used this function on jquery but It didn't work.

```
$(window).focus(); or $(document).focus();
```

when the window focus is out I need to alert the user and then refresh the page

I saw something like this in Comet Chat script when the focus is out and the window is changed there was a function to recall sounds (dings)

Is there anything compatible with Jquery to handle window focus ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way to highjack the user's screen. If there were, spam sites would hold us all hostage. The website markup does not have as much control over the client as you might think. Always assume that the user has more power over his/her desktop than you do.

Even if you could accomplish your goal, the users could still cheat by connecting using a program other than a web browser. Enforcing your "security" (or cheat prevention) solely client side is nearly *always* a bad idea. You need to find a way to make your fix server side, where the user has no control.

Comment: I know all these but I have seen similar website doing it and it works there, just check out @nav reply , and my comment please

Answer (score 0):

Well `.focus()` is usually just for input elements.

You could try some combination of `click` and `mouseover`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).blur(function() { 
    // naughty naughty handling code
});
```

Comment: thanks , it worked , but if they click on the flash games and they want to play it , this script alert that focus is lost , now how to include a flash object in page in window focus or how to ignore it by the script

Comment: @MacTaylor and using $(document) fails also?